# How to resolve Unity3d Editor lags with increased pool size for parallaxer script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, parallax, lag

I am creating a 2d Platformer game.

When the pool size for the parallaxer script attached to my prefab is increased, the Unity3D application lags and freezes in larger pool sizes. This event was not present previously in other projects with substantially larger pool sizes. The event seems to persist regardless of game aspect.

**Parallaxer Script with Prefab Attached**
Pool Size: 10 (where it begins to lag)
Shift Speed: -1
Spawn Rate: 1

Y Spawn Range :
Min Y: 0
Max Y: 2.72
Default Spawn Pos
X: 12.81 
Y:-0.03 Z:0
Spawn Immediate: Unchecked
Immediate Spawn Pos
X: 0 Y: 0 Z: 0
Target Aspect Ratio:
X: 10 Y: 16

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Parallaxer : MonoBehaviour {

    class PoolObject {
        public Transform transform;
        public bool inUse;
        public PoolObject(Transform t) { transform = t; }
        public void Use() { inUse = true; }
        public void Dispose() { inUse = false; }
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public struct YSpawnRange {
        public float minY;
        public float maxY;
    }

    public GameObject Prefab;
    public int poolSize;
    public float shiftSpeed;
    public float spawnRate;

    public YSpawnRange ySpawnRange;
    public Vector3 defaultSpawnPos;
    public bool spawnImmediate;
    public Vector3 immediateSpawnPos;
    public Vector2 targetAspectRatio;

    float spawnTimer;
    PoolObject[] poolObjects;
    float targetAspect;
    GameManager game;

    void Awake() {
        Configure();
    }

    void Start() {
        game = GameManager.Instance;
    }

    void OnEnable() {
        GameManager.OnGameOverConfirmed += OnGameOverConfirmed;
    }

    void OnDisable() {
        GameManager.OnGameOverConfirmed -= OnGameOverConfirmed;
    }

    void OnGameOverConfirmed() {
        for (int i = 0; i < poolObjects.Length; i++) {
            poolObjects[i].Dispose();
            poolObjects[i].transform.position = Vector3.one * 1000;
        }
        Configure();
    }

    void Update() {
        if (game.GameOver) return;

        Shift();
        spawnTimer += Time.deltaTime;
        if (spawnTimer > spawnRate) {
            Spawn();
            spawnTimer = 0;
        }
    }

    void Configure() {
        //spawning pool objects
        targetAspect = targetAspectRatio.x / targetAspectRatio.y;
        poolObjects = new PoolObject[poolSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < poolObjects.Length; i++) {
            GameObject go = Instantiate(Prefab) as GameObject;
            Transform t = go.transform;
            t.SetParent(transform);
            t.position = Vector3.one * 1000;
            poolObjects[i] = new PoolObject(t);
        }

        if (spawnImmediate) {
            SpawnImmediate();
        }
    }

    void Spawn() {
        //moving pool objects into place
        Transform t = GetPoolObject();
        if (t == null) return;
        Vector3 pos = Vector3.zero;
        pos.y = Random.Range(ySpawnRange.minY, ySpawnRange.maxY);
        pos.x = (defaultSpawnPos.x * Camera.main.aspect) / targetAspect;
        t.position = pos;
    }

    void SpawnImmediate() {
        Transform t = GetPoolObject();
        if (t==null) return;
        Vector3 pos = Vector3.zero;
        pos.y = Random.Range(ySpawnRange.minY, ySpawnRange.maxY);
        pos.x = (immediateSpawnPos.x * Camera.main.aspect) / targetAspect;
        t.position = pos; 
        Spawn();
    }

    void Shift() {
        //loop through pool objects 
        //moving them
        //discarding them as they go off screen
        for (int i = 0; i < poolObjects.Length; i++) {
            poolObjects[i].transform.position += Vector3.right * shiftSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            CheckDisposeObject(poolObjects[i]);
        }
    }

    void CheckDisposeObject(PoolObject poolObject) {
        //place objects off screen
        if (poolObject.transform.position.x < (-defaultSpawnPos.x * Camera.main.aspect) / targetAspect) {
            poolObject.Dispose();
            poolObject.transform.position = Vector3.one * 1000;
        }
    }

    Transform GetPoolObject() {
        //retrieving first available pool object
        for (int i = 0; i < poolObjects.Length; i++) {
            if (!poolObjects[i].inUse) {
                poolObjects[i].Use();
                return poolObjects[i].transform;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Consider looking into a Queue data type, rather than a general array of PoolObjects. Queues are designed for this specific use case! Queue<PoolObject> is what you could use to reduce your for-loop checks.

Comment: Here's some links to my implementation of generic PoolableObjects for a passion project I worked on awhile back: https://github.com/ErikOverflow/SimpleIncremental/blob/master/Simple%20Incremental/Assets/Scripts/Monobehaviours/ObjectPooler.cs and https://github.com/ErikOverflow/SimpleIncremental/blob/master/Simple%20Incremental/Assets/Scripts/Monobehaviours/PoolableObject.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change an object's transform.position it can be an expensive process if the object is nested inside of other objects in your game hierarchy. Rather than change the object's transform, consider setting the GameObject to inactive when it is not in use. Additionally, rather than iterate over your list of PoolObjects every time you need to GetPoolObject(), consider creating a Queue of unused objects. This serves 2 purposes:

1. You no longer need to track if an object is inUse via a property
2. You do not need to iterate through all of your objects to find an available one.

Example of a queue:

```
Queue<PoolObject> availableObjects = new Queue<PoolObject>();

class PoolObject 
{
    public Transform transform;
    public bool inUse;
    public PoolObject(Transform t) { transform = t; }
    public void Use() { inUse = true; }
    public void Dispose() { inUse = false; }
}

void CheckDisposeObject(PoolObject poolObject) 
{
    //place objects off screen
    if (poolObject.transform.position.x < (-defaultSpawnPos.x * Camera.main.aspect) / targetAspect) 
    {
        availableObjects.Enqueue(poolObject);
        poolObject.transform.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}

Transform GetPooledObject()
{
    if(availableObjects.Count > 0)
        Transform poolObj = availableObjects.Dequeue();
        poolObj.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        return poolObj;
    else
        return null;
}
```

Comment: How would I revise my current Parallaxer script with the suggestion you added? Thanks!

Comment: You would likely want to remove any of your for loops in your code outside of the Shift() method, and instead manage your pooled objects via queues. I would also recommend looking into the example pool scripts I provided in a comment on your post. Rather than trying to manage all poolable objects and pooling in one script, separate the "PoolObject" as its own monobehaviour, and the "ObjectPooler" as a separate Monobehaviour that manages them. @zelici